# Communicate with LWC outside of hierarchy

Tags: lightning-web-components

I know it is possible to call a function on a child LWC by annotating the function with @api and using a querySelector to find the child BUT is it possible to do similar for a LWC which is not nested and not in the hierarchy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of [Lightning Message service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-message-service/documentation) to communicate with components that are not in same hierarchy if you are not in communities. If you are using communities, you can use [Pub sub module](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.events_pubsub) to communicate with components.

The advantage over pubsub is that message channels aren’t restricted to a single page. Any component in a Lightning Experience application that listens for events on a message channel updates when it receives a message. It works between Lightning web components, Aura components, and Visualforce pages in any tab or in any pop-out window in Lightning Experience. It also works across namespaces.

Comment: So I am using LMS to pass data. Can I call a function from LMS or would it be a case of updating a variable which then triggers a function?

Comment: @JonathanAndrewFox Correct. You can only pass in data, the receiving end would need to call the function.